# Shell: How to delete mercurial files using an automated script?

Tags: shell

I want to make a tiny script that deleted ALL the files in my Symfony project that **mercuaril** gives me as unwanted files.

For example:

```
hg status:

...

? web/images/lightwindow/._arrow-up.gif
? web/images/lightwindow/._black-70.png
? web/images/lightwindow/._black.png
? web/images/lightwindow/._nextlabel.gif
? web/images/lightwindow/._pattern_148-70.png
? web/images/lightwindow/._pattern_148.gif
? web/images/lightwindow/._prevlabel.gif
? web/js/._lightwindow.js
? web/sfPropel15Plugin
? web/sfProtoculousPlugin
```

I would like to delete all the files that are marked with the **?**. ONLY THOSE. Not the ones modified -**M**-, and so on.

I'm trying to do a mini-script for that:

```
hg status | grep '^?*' | rm -f
```

I don't know if it is OK. Could you help me with one?

Comment: With both current answers **and** your solution, you should really be aware of the problems `rm`+`xargs` without `NULL` terminated strings causes. If you file names contain spaces, you may get yourself a rather nasty surprise...

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
hg status|awk '/^? /{gsub(/^\? /, "", $0);print;}'|while read line; do
    rm -f "$line"
done
```

The awk command matches everything starting with '`?`', and executes the block '{gsub(/^\? /, "", $0);print;}'. The block does a substitution on `$0` (the entire line matched), replacing the starting "? " with nothing, making `$0` just the filename. The `print` then prints `$0` (print with no args defaults to printing `$0`)

So the awk output prints a list of filenames, one per line. This is fed into a read loop, which removes each.

This will preserve whitespace in filenames, but it will break if there are any filenames that contain newlines! Handling newlines gracefully is impossible with `hg status` as the input, since `hg status` prints newline-separated output

Comment: Thanks. Could you please explain a little bit the code? Never wrorked with awk :/

Comment: I'm using it (hg status|awk '/^? /{gsub(/^\? /, "", $0);print;}'), but it brings me: **M apps/cms/config/routing.yml** Which should not be in the results. If I use **hg status -u** could work? because it brings all the unknown status?

Comment: I'm not familiar with `hg`, but this is proably because it's printing on stderr - try using `hg status 2>/dev/null` or `hg status 2>&1 >/dev/null`.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing `xargs`, which takes the input and gives it to a command as parameters (right now you're actually sending them to `rm`'s standard input, which isn't meaningful). Something like:

```
hg status | grep '^?' | cut -d' ' -f2 | xargs rm -f
```

Note: it won't work if your file names contain spaces. It'd still be possible but you need to be more clever.

Comment: You can fix your whitespace issues with a few small changes: `hg status | grep '^?' | cut -b 2- | xargs -rL1 -i'{}' rm -rf '{}'`, but this will have issues with single quotes in filenames which my awk/read loop above does not.